# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'LDServiceHost.ILDService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, service

***Error :***

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'LDServiceHost.ILDService' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

**App.Config :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\_Demos\EF Code Samples\EFLayers\LDPresentation\app_tracelog.svclog"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="C:\_Demos\EF Code Samples\EFLayers\LDPresentation\app_messages.svclog"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>



    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ILDService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                      enabled="false" />
                  <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                  </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

      <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      </diagnostics>

        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/LibraryService/LDService/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ILDService"
                contract="LDServiceHost.ILDService" name="WSHttpBinding_ILDService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**How to solve?**

Comment: Are you passing in the endpoint name `WSHttpBinding_ILDService` when creating a service proxy? Could you post that part of your client side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is in a library project. Config files are application not library specific in .NET so the config needs to be in in the .exe not in the DLL

Copy the system.serviceModel section of your DLLs config into a config file for your application and it should find it OK

Btw: Its generally better to keep a question all in one place rather than add links to external sites - these have a habit of getting out of sync with SO and so the question ends up not making much sense